# Javascript Canvas not showing image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am currently working on a Javascript Canvas project (never coded in Js or used canvas before) and need some help regarding drawing an image with a border in the centre of the canvas.

I currently have a Person.js where the rectangle and image of the person are drawn:

```
var Person = (function () {
function Person(pName, pImageUrl) {
    this.setId(Person.sTotalNodes++);
    this.setName(pName);
    this.mImage = new Image();
    this.setImageUrl(pImageUrl);
    this.mPartners = new Array();

}
Person.sTotalNodes = 0;
Person.prototype.getId = function () {
    return this.mId;
};
Person.prototype.setId = function (pId) {
    this.mId = pId;
};
Person.prototype.draw = function (context) {

    //draw rectangle
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context.translate(canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.5);
    var context = c.getContext("2d");
    context.rect(0,0,160,210);
    context.fillStyle = '#0073E6';
    context.fill();
    context.stroke();
    //get image and draw
    context.drawImage(this.getImage(), 0, 0);

};
Person.prototype.setName = function (pName) {
    this.mName = pName;
};
Person.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this.mName;
};
Person.prototype.setImageUrl = function (pImageUrl) {
    this.mImageUrl = pImageUrl;
    this.mImage.src = pImageUrl;
};
Person.prototype.getImageUrl = function () {
    return this.mImageUrl;
};
Person.prototype.getImage = function () {
    /* when you first get this it will not return a proper image
        you need to use the getImageUrl function and then build a new image */
    return this.mImage;
};
Person.prototype.getPartner = function (pIndex) {
    return this.mPartners[pIndex];
};
Person.prototype.numPartners = function () {
    return this.mPartners.length;
};
Person.prototype.addPartner = function (pPartner) {
    this.mPartners.push(pPartner);
};

return Person;
```

})();

But once I add `context.translate(canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.5);`
 in order to place the origin in the centre of my canvas, only the rectangle draws? Am I mission out something? (have also tried placing the `context.translate` in my main.js where `topPerson.draw(context);` is called to draw the first person from the tree.

main.js (where I call first person of tree to be drawn)

```
// add the onLoad event listener to initialise our canvas
if(window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, true);
}

function onLoad() {
var canvas;
var context;
var exampleFamilyTrees;
var topPerson;

var previousMousePosition;

function initialise() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    if (!canvas) {
        alert('Error: Canvas element not found');
        return;
    }

    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!context) {
        alert('Error: Unable to get canvas context');
        return;
    }
    exampleFamilyTrees = new ExampleFamilyTrees();
    topPerson = exampleFamilyTrees.getFamilyTree(0);


}
function draw(){
    context.translate(canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.5);
    topPerson.draw(context);

}

function update(){

}

function animationLoop(){
    update();
    draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop);
}
initialise();
animationLoop();
}
```

Comment: `canvas` in the `Person.prototype.draw`, `context.translate(canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.5);` should be undefined. Also, if you're already passing the context, you don't need to define `c` with `getElementById()`, and therefore you don't need to reset `context` to `c.getContext('2d')` : just use `var c = context.canvas`. But I'm not sure this is the only problem. e.g, you'll need to wait for the image has loaded before being able to draw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place `translate` before even `context.rect`

Comment: in my Person.js I do have the `context.translate(canvas.width * 0.5, canvas.height * 0.5);` placed on line 2 of the code snippet above. Do you mean to do `translate.context.rect`? Your answer is too brief for me, sorry

Comment: You should place it right after `var context = canvas.getContext("2d");`

Comment: That works with drawing the rectangle but my image is still missing? I do call the image to draw in my main.js. I will post code for that.

Comment: You should remove `var context = canvas.getContext("2d");` since you are passing the context directly to the `Person.draw` method.

Comment: I have tried removing that line from the main, did not show either pic or rectangle then tried removing from Person.js but had the same outcome

Comment: you should remove it only from the Person.js

Comment: I tried that but neither rectangle or image show on the canvas

Comment: Try replacing `var context = canvas.getContext("2d");` with `with var context = c.getContext("2d");` in the person.js

Comment: Still no rectangle or image shown, also no console errors show

Comment: Hi, I still havent managed to find a solution for this, any ideas what is going on?

Comment: sure, for Person.js and main.js

Comment: It would be nice if you could set up a jsFiddle or something else that I could tinker with. For example you can use https://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you'd be able to help me out with something? we can use the same link above to code but I did send you the project

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: I have tried to add a for loop in order to draw the other nodes such as children from array and then place them onto the canvas at a set position

Comment: try to figure out what is going on, I will help you tomorrow if I have enough time